# How to pass data.bind in POST request using C#

Tags: c#, json, api, dynamics-crm

i have a web app connected with crm Dynamics 365. I want to create record in an entity using API, but the entity has lookup fields to another entities. I tried this code but it gives bad request error. How can i send the values of the lookup fields in the API?

```
JSON:{
"msdyn_name": "Asset",
"msdyn_account@odata.bind": "/accounts(7f7e031b-0e20-ea11-a810-000d3a2d54fd)",
"new_externalproj@odata.bind": "/msdynce_externalprojects(ee3f03c6-751f-ea11-a810-000d3a27b751)" }
```

```
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string json = serializer.Serialize(new
{
     msdyn_name = "Asset",
     msdyn_account = "7f7e031b-0e20-ea11-a810-000d3a2d54fd",
     new_externalproj = "ee3f03c6-751f-ea11-a810-000d3a27b751"
});
var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://XXX.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/msdyn_customerassets");
httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", String.Format("Bearer {0}", result.AccessToken));
httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("OData-MaxVersion", "4.0");
httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("OData-Version", "4.0");
httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";

using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
{streamWriter.Write(json);
}
var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
var responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: use json.net and a dictionary.

Comment: @DanielA.White can you show me a code sample?